# Calculating Metrics (Recall, Precision, F1) in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I use one of the pre-trained sentence-encoder from tensorflow and now the plan is to evaluate the metrics (recall, precision and F1) based on my input and the corresponding embeddings. The input of my model is a bunch of many different texts (around 2000).
My plan is to determine and visualize these metrics.

```
my_model = hub.load("path-to-universal-sentence-encoder")
my_texts = [...]
my_embeddings = [my_model(text) for text in my_texts]
```

What are the possibilities, and the proper steps to determine the metrics and visualize them?

Answer (score 0):

To Evaluate the metrics(recall, precision, F1 Score) based on your input and the corresponding embeddings, you can compare your model predictions.

Kindly follow below step-by step instructions :

> First step We need to prepare our data, make sure we need input texts and corresponding labels. if we dont have labels, we can't able to compute metrics  like precision, recall and F1 score.

> In second step, we need to get the predictions, we can use Universal Sentence Encoder to get embeddings for texts.

> In third step we need to prepare our labels. for example positive or negative labels, make sure these labels are in the right format for comparison.

> In fourth step, if we want to compute distances or similarities between these embeddings to make predictions. we can use cosine similarity or Euclidean distance.

> In Fifth step, we need to make predictions. Using the distance metric, compare the embeddings of your texts to get predictions. For example, you might set a threshold for cosine similarity above which you consider two texts to be similar.

> In final step, With predictions and ground truth labels, We can compute metrics.